# Search within nested Django JSONField (either via Django ORM or raw sql)

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, jsonb

**Edit:** Added solution below. No-one was able to suggest a native Postgres, one-hit search-and-replace so I had to parse the log in Python and then do an update.

*Versions*: `Django==1.10.3` and `Postgres 9.6`

Is there a way to search within a nested Django `JSONField` (backed by Postgres `jsonb`) for a specific key/value state? Ideally this would be a native Django but I can break out into raw sql if necessary.

e.g. search for one or more occurrences of `{"status":"running}` within the following data:

```
{"subtask1": {"status":"running"},
 "subtask2": {"status":"complete"}}
```

*Background:*

I'm using a `JSONField` to log the current status of long-running subtasks. Each subtask updates it's element of the json field selectively via a nativePostgres `jsonb_set()` operation on the server.

After each subtask, I want to query the `log` field to see whether this subtask was the last to complete. If all are complete (ie no occurences for `{"status":"running"}` within the nested json tree) then I'll update the main `.complete` field for the Django `RunningTask` instance.

*Sample & simplified model:*

```
class LongRunningTask(models.model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    log = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default=dict)
```

*Example data for `log` field:*

```
{"subtask1": {"status":"running"},
 "subtask2": {"status":"complete"}}
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

*Note:*

I've tried Django's built-in `contains` operator but this won't find the values because they are nested one level down. I got excited by the prospect of the [`values` operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#std:fieldlookup-hstorefield.contains) but from my testing it's not implemented on the `JSONField` (only `HStoreField`).

**Solution:**

Couldn't find a native Postgres one-hit search and replace call, so I ended up parsing the log in Python after each sub-task completed to find out if it's the last one. I hope to find a better solution in time.

```
_current_log = LongRunningTask.objects.get(pk=current_task.id).log
_statuses = [True if _current_log[i]["status"] == "complete"
             else False
             for i in _current_log]
if all(_statuses):
    LongRunningTask.objects.filter(pk=adhoc_task.id).update(complete=True)
```

Comment: There must be unque key , you can't do reference for "subtask1","subtask2" better change it to "subtask".

Comment: Hi @PiyushS.Wanare - that is the unique identifier for the subtask, so can't be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
import json

all_completed=True
json_dict=json.loads(json_log)
for key,value in json_dict.items():
   if json_dict[key]['status']!='complete':
       all_completed=False
       break
```

This is just a hint. You can change it according to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks @Mohammed for your comment. I am hoping to do this within the Postgres query rather than in Python, to avoid race conditions between each sub-task updating the record.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a native way to do this, although I have a gut instinct that someone with a better comprehension of the jsonb methods in Postgres could come up with one. I'm accepting this for now as I went with a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
LongRunningTask.objects.filter(log__values__contains={"status":"running"})
```

Comment: I saw the `values` operator in the docs but it's not implemented for `JSONField` unfortunately - only `HStoreField`.